# How can I fix the size of the last subplot?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to have 5x4 subplots, one for each group. I wrote the following code:

```
axeng = []
for i in range(5):
    for ii in range(4):
        axeng.append([i,ii])`

yy = (0.5, 4.5, 9.5, 14.5, 19.5, 24.5)

xx=np.arange(0.5,10)
f,axes = plt.subplots(5,4,figsize=(50,50), sharex=True, sharey=True)
cbar_ax = f.add_axes([.92, .3, .03, .4])

for i in range(20):
    paxesrow = tuple(axeng[i])[0]
    paxescol = tuple(axeng[i])[1]
    # gnuplot, jet, YlGnBu, GnBu_r
    
    g=sns.heatmap(heat[i],cmap="viridis",vmin=0.1,vmax=1,
                  ax=axes[paxesrow,paxescol],linewidth=.1,
                  cbar=True if i==3 else False,
                  
                  cbar_ax=cbar_ax if i==3 else None,
                  square=False)
    g.set_yticks(yy)
    g.set_xticks(xx)
    g.set_yticklabels([' ','25',' ','15',' ','5'],fontsize=33)
    g.set_xticklabels([' ','2',' ','4',' ','6',' ','8',' ','10'],fontsize=33,rotation=0)


f.tight_layout(rect=[1, 1, 1, 1])
f.suptitle('Behavior of all subgroups',fontsize=70,y=.93)
cbar=axes[tuple(axeng[3])[0],tuple(axeng[3])[1]].collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=35)
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the image, the last subplot is scaled, but I have no idea why that would be the case.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, there's no reference to `heat` data.

Comment: It seems to me that the scaling of the bottom right axis is completely off; could you try "manually" setting the plot limits for each plot (i.e. use `g.set_xlim(0,10)` and   `g.set_ylim(0,25)` at the end of the `for i in range(20):` loop)?